# How to open a SQLite3 database without risking creating a new one?

Tags: database, sqlite

If I accidentally pass a non-existent database file to `sqlite3` I'd like to get notified with an error or something similar.

But the command `sqlite3 my.db` will open `my.db` **or** create a it if it doesn't exist. The same behavior exists if I issue the following:

```
> sqlite3
sqlite> .open my.db
```

If there an option where I pass a database file to be opened *but that fails in case it doesn't exist?*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the SQLite C API, the function [sqlite3_open_v2](http://sqlite.org/c3ref/open.html) would allow you to specify whether a new database is to be created.

The `sqlite3` command-line shell always specifies the CREATE flag, and has no mechanism to disable it.

You could execute a command like `.dbinfo` to check whether you actually have a database, or write a shell script/batch file that checks for the file before actually executing `sqlite3`.

Answer (score 0):

You could just check if the file exists on the filesystem.

Comment: That's what I'm doing at the moment. So the answer is "no, there isn't an option"?

Comment: When i had the same problem, i didn't find an option.